# Java: Correct Iterating through types

Tags: java, android, json

```
        {
           "long_name" : "1",
           "short_name" : "1",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "ABC Street",
           "short_name" : "ABC Street",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "ABC Town",
           "short_name" : "ABC",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "ABC Area",
           "short_name" : "ABCA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "ABC L",
           "short_name" : "ABCL",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Country",
           "short_name" : "CT",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "1234",
           "short_name" : "1234",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
```

I have this JSON from Google Maps and successfully convert it to a GSON Object:

```
class address_component{
    public String long_name;
    public String short_name;
    public String[] types;
}
```

How should I iterate through my types now? I need to save the street, street_number and town each in it's own field. The only thing I thought of is this, but it doesn't look right/good to me:

```
if (types.contains("street_number")) {
   street_number = short_name
} else if (types.contains("route")) {
   street = short_name
}
```

And of course looping through each address_component. How can I do it better?

Comment: You should use a for loop to iterate through... I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish or how you are trying to do it... the full code would be nice so I know how you are trying to store the values

Comment: Where are you saving these fields to? For each `address_component` you have an array of types, what do you need to do with these? More context would help.

Comment: Nothing fancy, I haven an Address Object with, fields street, street number, city, country, etc..

Comment: Well, the street number, street etc is not always in the same order. I need to know which of those JSON Objects is a street, a street number etc, by checking on the types array.

Comment: Based on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) your approach isn't wrong. The geocoding api does not return the same results for every input you so are correct to check that fields exist instead of assuming. Just use a for loop on the JSONArray and check types first. If the values match, then grab the outer JSON object.

Comment: Ok thanks, if you type an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `types` arrays are each one or two records long, and you're only looking for three data types. There's some wasted effort in your approach, but the `contains(String)` thing in its current form doesn't waste THAT much effort because the numbers are so small.

An obvious way to avoid unnecessary work is to stop doing further `contains("street")` checks after you have found the street, and the same for the other fields. This can be a simple extra condition:

```
if (street_number == null && types.contains("street_number")) {
  street_number = short_name
} else if (street == null && types.contains("route")) {
  street = short_name 
}
```

You didn't post enough of your code to tell what you're doing in the bigger picture. I see two potential problems with a much larger cost than the if-contains-else-if-contains section that you're asking about.

1. You're iterating seven (or more) of these address types records while searching for the data. Do you `break` iterating once you have the three items that you need and skip over however many more address_type's there may be?
2. Does your code load the entire JSON structure in memory before you begin processing or does it take a streaming approach?
3. The big whopper is to take a good look at the documentation of the API that you're querying. If there's a way to tell the server which data types you're looking for, then the server can filter everything you don't need out of the response. You'll still iterate, but you won't be discarding so much data. This saves bandwidth, memory and CPU on the mobile device. The server has a lot more of each of these, so best to let it do the work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Ok it seems that my approach wasn't that bad as I thought. Thanks for the null check idea, that's a bit better performing.

For 1. I'm actually creating an Object via GSON, and I'm only iterating over the fields I need.

For 2. My code does indeed load the whole JSON everytime, but it isn't that long... The streaming approach wouldn't work tough because I can't create the GJSON Object any more then.

For 3. It's the Google Maps API, and as far as I know that doesn't work...